# What does "damn" exactly mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Today I came across sentence which was:

> People are no **damn** good.

It got me into thinking that since the word "damn" has been used before "good", a noun, it should be an adjective and the only meaning of damn as an adjective I could find was - "very, extremely" but then does it imply that people are not extremely good although they are but not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'Damn'** works here as an *interjection* giving an emphasis to the whole expression '*people are no good*' (=~ are bad).

Answer (score 2):

From the [**Urban Dictionary**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=damn), I select the meanings which fit to your sentence:

1. An expression of dismay.
2. An expression of awe.
3. "Giving a damn", the act of caring about something.
4. The act of condemning someone, most often to hell or an equivalent place.
5. "Damn you", a verbal middle finger equivalent to "go to hell".
6. An expression of surprise.
7. **"Damn well", a sort of sentence enhancer, most often used with the word "better".**
8. **An adjective you can stick before phrases like "near" and "close to" to raise the sentence's severity.**
9. An exclamation interchangeable with "Wow".
10. **An adjective you can stick in front of absolutely any noun to add a feeling of stigma to your sentence.**

(I previously had an improperly documented answer.)